# How to create a Gin index on a geometry column in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4, spatial-index

According to [pgAdmin 4 4.21 documentation » Creating or Modifying a Table »](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/latest/index_dialog.html)

> Select gin to create a GIN index. A GIN index may improve performance when managing two-dimensional geometric data types and nearest-neighbor searches

We should create a Gin index for geometric column if we intend to use Nearest-neighbor searches, Which I do!

However, when defining Gin index it asks for **Operator Class** and there are two options there (`jsonb_path_obs` and `gin_int_ops`) but none of them works with Geometry type.

Could someone please tell me how to create a Gin index on a Geometry type column?

P.S by geometry I mean PostGIS's geometry column type

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please [link to the thing you are quoting](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/latest/index_dialog.html) so we don't have to go searching for it.

That looks like a bug in the pgadmin4 docs.  They seem to have the GIN and GiST labels reversed in those descriptions.  GIN supports multiple keys better than GiST does, but doesn't support nearest-neighbor or spatial.  You want a GiST index.

Comment: Sorry but the documentation was on 127.0.0.1 so I couldn't provide link. Yes, I should have searched and provide a link on the internet. I will edit my question and add your link to it.

Comment: Thanks by the way.(also +1)

Comment: OK, I see.  I've fled a doc bug for this, https://redmine.postgresql.org/issues/5734.

Comment: That would be great as new users like me could really be misled